# Rollback transaction within Service using @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, database, transactions, rollback

Good evening, guys.

I have a method called from an endpoint that saves an objects on my database, and I'd like to add some "protection" to this code by rolling back the transaction in the case of any exception occur inside the service.

I'm using JAX-RS for the REST API part and OracleDB as the database. My code is as follows.

**Endpoint:**

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createAcordo(AcordoDTO acordoDTO) {
    return acordosService.save(acordoDTO, token);
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class)
public Response save(AcordoDTO acordoDTO, String token) {
    try {
        ... some bisiness logic and validation

        Acordo acordo = acordoRepository.save(AcordoConverter.toAcordo(acordoDTO));
        UserDTO usr = getUserInfoFromToken();
        ApprovalDTO approvalDTO = new ApprovalDTO ();
        approvalDTO .setUser(usr.getName()); // this method is throwing null pointer exception  
                                             // because usr is null

        return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(acordo).build();
       
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new SystemErrorException().toResponse();
    }
}
```

The code above, despite the exception and @Transactional anotation, is saving the new `Acordo` object to the database. What I'd expect to happen, however, is that the full transaction was rolledback and no objects were saved.
In summary, what I'd like to know is:

1. I'm misundertaing any concepts regarding @Transactional usage ?
2. How to fix this code to achieve de desired goal (rollback) ?

**PS.1** - I tried without `try/catch` block and the result is the same. The save() still commits the object to the database.

**PS.2** - The acordoRepository.save() has @Transaction annotation.

**PS.3** - I tried adding `TransactionSynchronizationRegistry.setRollbackOnly()` inside the catch block and **it worked**. However (for me) it looks like more like a cheat than a proper solution.

**PS.4** - After I used `TransactionSynchronizationRegistry.setRollbackOnly()` the transaction status was `STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK` and in all other tests it was `STATUS_ACTIVE`.

**UPDATE 1** 
My `acordoRepository.save()` is as follows. I tried to check whether there was one or two transacions. In order to do that, I tried (not sure  it's a good idea) to print the `tsr.getTransactionKey()` both on my `Service.save()` and `acordoRepository.save()` and the result was **the same key**, which led me to believe that there's only one transaction.

```
@Resource
TransactionSynchronizationRegistry tsr; // I injected it here
                                        // for testing purposes
@Transactional
public T save(T entity) {
    if (entity.getId() == null) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    } else {
        entityManager.merge(entity);
    }

   entityManager.flush();

   return find(entity.getId());
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** 
My `persistence.xml` is as follows.

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="namePU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:/nameDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <jar-file>lib/client-notification-1.30.jar</jar-file>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false"/>
      <!-- desabilita JSR-303 no save/update -->
      <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="none"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Best regards, 
Thomaz.

Comment: You can throw custom runtime exception and handle it in exception handler or if you need try catch you can then throw your exception in catch block in this way then you can say your client that request is failed.

Comment: Didn't undestand your sugestion @Javid. You're saying that I could change method signature to `save(AcordoDTO x) throws SomeCustomRuntimeException` ? Could you try to explain it a bit further, please ?

Comment: @palmeiira I bet your `acordoRepository.save` brings an `@Transactional` with `propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`. This would explain this behavior since a nested transaction would be created which will be commited so when the outer transaction in the basic method that you have failed it did not roll back the nested transaction. Is this the case?

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos I tried printing the TransactionSynchronizationRegistry.getTransactionKey() and it showed me the same key on both methods. I'll update my question to explain a little further.

Comment: @palmeiira instead of showing us every fix you have tried, please show us all the code that is relevant. The nested method, the DTO and everything else. Then we could help you with specific reasons for why this is happening

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos sorry for the lack of information. I posted what I thought was the necessary. Could you please be a little more specific on which methods/ classes do you want me to add ?

Comment: @palmeiira the `entityManager` still is missing on how it is configured. Do you have manually configured it?

Comment: How is your datasource configured? Per the Oracle JDBC documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html, datasources are created in autocommit mode.  Your connection configuration may have autocommit disabled, but it would not hurt to confirm.

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos added _persistence.xml_ on **UPDATE 2**

Comment: @j_b My connection indeed has autocommit disabled but after reading the doc you posted I failed to see the harm it can cause. Could you please try to explain with more details ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `@Transactional` method to rollback you must not catch the exception inside that method. Remove the `catch(Exception)` from `save` and catch it in createAcordo instead. That should work.

Comment: @ewrammer thanks for answering, but as I said on **PS.1**: removing the `try/catch` block didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try with
Throwable.class instead Exception.class since throwable is super class of if with remove try/catch
by the way bydefault spring will take care of rollBack but even if we are declaring explicitly then it will check for checked/unchecked exception
**specifically**- rollbackFor = {AnyException.class} for checked exception becuse runtimeException will take care by spring itself
you may look this example: https://www.netsurfingzone.com/spring/transactional-rollbackfor-example-using-spring-boot/

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work as well.

Comment: After you updated your answer, I realized you're talking about Spring's @Transactional. Just to clarify: I'm not using Spring, I'm using JAX-RS.

Answer (score 0):

Whell after I couldn't make comment with code :)
I'm making an answer:
I think that you can just use an exception like this:

```
@Transactional(rollbackOn = CustomeException.class)
public Response save(AcordoDTO acordoDTO, String token) {
    try {
        ... some bisiness logic and validation
        if(! valid)
            throw new CustomeException();

        Acordo acordo = acordoRepository.save(AcordoConverter.toAcordo(acordoDTO));
        UserDTO usr = getUserInfoFromToken();
        ApprovalDTO approvalDTO = new ApprovalDTO ();
        approvalDTO .setUser(usr.getName()); // this method is throwing null pointer exception  
                                         // because usr is null
        // if this code throws any exception then throw runtime exception in your catch bloke
        return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(acordo).build();
   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CustomeException();
    }
}
```